# How to develop with WebSphere 8.5 traditional on OS X

Tags: eclipse-plugin, websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

It's my understanding that WebSphere 8.5 traditional is not compatible or will not run on OSX. I am looking for solutions for developers to develop with a WebSphere 8.5 traditional server locally.

Could we setup some servers on a windows machine so they can be used remotely during development?

I downloaded the Eclipse plugin but it gives me the warning saying OS X is not compatible with WebSphere traditional and to give it a remote server address. I tried to point eclipse to a server on a windows PC but it still wants a runtime installation directory.

I found a [single thread on WASDev](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7caf82a0-9913-4fb6-b8ea-1cdd23a8d4ae) with a similar question talking about runtime stubs with a dead link.

I tried using a liberty server but I get nothing but null pointer exceptions and JMX errors, I don't think this is a valid alternative in my corporate environment.

Answer (score 4):

For developing against WebSphere traditional on OSX, you could try Docker! We've published developer edition versions of 8.5.5.9 and 9.0.0.0, see:

- https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/06/15/websphere-traditional-ibm-http-server-docker-hub/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/

The Dockerfiles used to produce these images are here, should you want to try building your own instead:

- https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional

However, your question is more specific to getting the tools working.

The last I read (and I'll try to confirm/update the answer when I do find it), is that the stubs are part of the full product install for RAD (selectable via Installation Manager).

Comment: Docker looks amazing... i'm stuck in the stone age over here though lol.

Comment: Finally got the traditional server back up and running.. took me out of work for a week. I'm trying to migrate to Liberty but now it looks like it doesn't support J2C entries?? is there an alternative to getting this to work?

Comment: With the release of WAS v9, both Liberty and the traditional server support EE7 and thus JCA 1.7 and below.  See IBM KnowledgeCenter topic http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_jca-1.7.html for details on configuring JCA in Liberty

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I tried Docker and the issue was that the Eclipse Websphere plugin won't allow localhost only "remote" Websphere connections. Since Docker exposes ports on localhost, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that traditional WAS doesn't run on OSX.  Remote servers are an option but traditional WAS is considered by some developers to be heavy and slow to restart, so your developers might appreciate something local and more nimble.  Liberty is supposed to run on OSX, and things that run on Liberty -usually- will run on traditional, so getting to the bottom of your Liberty problems  might be useful.  If you haven't already, posting your question on WASDev might reach someone that has a better answer than this one.

Comment: Liberty does run on OSX. I helped build it there. ;)

Comment: @ebullient do you know where I can find the runtime stubs for a traditional 8.5 server? i'm going to try and setup a pc with a few servers running on it.

Comment: What do you mean by runtime stubs?

Comment: @FRowe according to that thread i linked, sounds like there is a runtime with empty methods so you can at least develop your code. Kind of like 'compileOnly' I guess with gradle. That is just my guess though, I was hoping someone knew where to get them.. I can't find them

Comment: The `WAS_HOME/dev` directory has JARs intended for compilation.